# Using Gitlab for Laravel project where the Server is Non-Internet facing

Tags: php, git, laravel, composer-php, gitlab

We have development, test, production servers that are intranet only and so cannot we cannot use Composer directly on these environments. I have developed a Laravel 5.2 application using WAMP as I can run composer on my PC, then manually copying the project folder onto the server for further development, testing and production. This all works ok but it is far from ideal.

We now have our own internal-facing Gitlab environment, so I have got an overview of how to use this to push my local code to it and then pull it onto the server development environment. However, in my naivety I thought all files would be pushed to the repo - but now I see there is a gitignore that stops folders such as the Vendor folder going across. Am I best just removing the gitignore details in this scenario and pushing everything across, as running composer on the servers is not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned above, if running composer on the server is "just not possible", then the only option you are left with is removing lines from .gitignore.

Let me remind you that it is not a good practice and you should try to somehow get composer running on the server. But if you just cannot, then...

PS: Please do not keep vendor directory in .gitignore and try to upload it via FTP or something like that. you will create a big mess and headache for yourself.

Comment: Thanks - Yes, it's not ideal, but it does sound like I will have to do it like you say.

Comment: Thank you. Don't forget to mark it solved to save others some time. :)